# Can you use one prepareForSegue to link 2 different views?

Tags: ios, swift2, segue

Is it possible to use a singular prepareForSegue() method to link to two different view controllers? I have 3 views and need to be able to go to view 1 and 3 from view 2. View controller 2 is a viewController with a custom tableview with the cells going to ViewController3 and a custom back button to go back to viewController1.

I have been googling around and have been playing around with something like this:

```
 @IBAction func newSearch(sender: AnyObject){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.performSegueWithIdentifier("view1", sender: self) })}

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){if segue.identifier == "newSearch"{
       let destView1: ViewController1 = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController1
    }else{
        let destView2 : ViewController3 = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController3}
```

I am currently able to tap on a cell and go to ViewController3. Yet when I try to tap on the newSearch button to go back to ViewController1 I get the error:

"Could not cast value of type 'app.ViewController1' to 'app.ViewController3'."

I don't fully understand why I would not go back when I am passing the correct segue.identifier. But I am quite new to swift and iOS development in general and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems that the destination view controller associated with the else clause segue is a ViewController1 instance,  not a 3.  It is safest to test for segue identifiers explicitly rather than relying on a catch-all else

Comment: depending on where the viewcontrollers lie in the UInavgationcotorllers' viewcontrller's array, you can easily hack this with a backward type cast to an object in the viewcontorllers of the navigationcontorller and hard code it if the object heirarchy never changes. otherwise, if the VC1 is the root of the navigationcontroller, and you want to pop from the VC3 to the VC1, then you pop to rootview controller, screw the segue crap. If VC1 isn't on the navigationController heiarchy, then simulate a pop by adding cutom event the backbutton with UIViewControlleAnimatedTransitioning

Comment: Easymode poping to whatever you want without typcasting:   NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

[self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is pass data back to the previous view controller, e.g.:

VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3

To pass data from VC2 to VC1 you would use:

```
self.delegate.aFunctionInVC1("some data")
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

where `delegate` is a reference to VC1.

So when you pushed VC2 from VC1, you should do this:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MyVC1ToVC2Segue", sender: self)
```

and then:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let vC2 = segue.destinationViewController as! VC2
    vC2.delegate = self
}
```

This is best implemented as a protocol. Here's an example:

**VC1**

```
protocol VC1Protocol {
    func doSomething(text: String)
}

class VC1: UIViewController, VC1Protocol {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func nextAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MyVC1toVC2Segue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let vC2 = segue.destinationViewController as! VC2
        vC2.delegate = self
    }

    func doSomething(text: String) {
        print(text)
    }
}
```

**VC2**

```
class VC2: UIViewController {

    var delegate: VC1Protocol!

    @IBAction func goBackAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.delegate.doSomething("Hello")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You often use a single `prepareForSegue` function to set up things before navigating to multiple different ViewControllers but this is usually done when the current view will be presenting the destination views (when using a 'show' or 'modal' segue).

It sounds like you'd like to move *back* through the navigation stack. Apple provides the [unwind segue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html) as a way to pass data back to a parent view controller while removing the view.

It took me a little while to get my head around it (as you actually create the `@IBAction` in the parent ViewController) but it is a powerful pattern.

Comment: Thank you! I took me awhile to figure it out but like you said it is quite a powerful pattern and it has a lot of future possibilities for me! I did find that if  you implement it on a back button from VC3 to VC2 and you use dismissViewControllerAnimated(_: , _: ) it will just back all the way back to the source view controller (VC1 for me).

Comment: You don't need to use `dismissViewControllerAnimated` when you implement an unwind segue, as the unwind segue will dismiss the ViewController for you. In your case, you're dismissing VC2 by including that command.